# Update the first row mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update my first row in my database. I use the `Limit 1` to only update the first row but nothing is happening. There are definitely matching rows but nothing changes in the database.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($player_fromsite as $match_player_in_game) {

    //$querytwo = 'INSERT INTO `'.$tablename.'` '.' (`'.$match_player_in_game.'`) '.'VALUES'.'("' . 'yes' . '")';

    $querytwo = 'UPDATE '.$tablename.' SET `'.$match_player_in_game.'` = "'.'yes'.'"   WHERE `'.$match_player_in_game.'` = "'.'NULL'.'" LIMIT 1';

    $querythree = 'UPDATE '.$tablename.' SET `'.$match_player_in_game.'` = "'.'yes'.'" WHERE `'.$match_player_in_game.'` = "'.'NULL'.'" LIMIT 1';

    for($a=0;$a<11;$a++){
        if($match_player_in_game == $home_players[$a]){
            // Insert a row of information into the table "example"
            mysql_query($querytwo) or die(mysql_error());       
       }else{
            mysql_query($querythree) or die(mysql_error());
       }
    }
}
```

Is the query correct?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the SQL that's generated, not your PHP code?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications, it's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly like you have here, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this. **AlWAYS** [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/php) any and all values to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL use `IS NULL` to compare with `NULL`.

For example: "`UPDATE table SET field = 'yes' WHERE field IS NULL`"

Answer (score 0):

NULL isn't a string, so you shouldn't be using = 'NULL', unless you actually set it to that string value.  Use IS NULL instead.

Comment: I removed the null statement and gave me the same results

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "first row".  First row based on an autoincrementing id value? First based on a timestamp date? You need to specify this as MySQL has no concept of "first row".

For example, if you do something like this in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1
```

You are not guaranteed to get the same record back each time.

Most likely you will need to specify an `ORDER BY` condition on a key column, as without it, you have no guarantee of which row your `LIMIT 1` will apply to.  I really can't think of a case where one might use `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` clause, as the two really go hand in hand.

So your query should look like:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = 'yes'
WHERE field IS NULL
ORDER BY some_key_field ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that even this query would not update the same row every time.  It would update the first record (as specified by ORDER BY) that has a NULL value for the specified field.  So if you ran this query 10 times, it would change 10 different records (assuming there are that many records with NULL values).